# Do commands in command substitution, process subsitution and in pipeline accept stdin inputs?

Tags: bash

I expect `cat` in the following command substitution, process substitution, and pipeline to accept stdin input, but

1. Why does it not output anything, after I provide stdin input `hello`

   ```
   $ echo $(cat)
   hello
   ```
2. Why does it not let me provide stdin input

   ```
   $ echo <(cat)
   /dev/fd/63
   ```
3. which  `cat` accepts my stdin input `hello`, and which `cat` outputs
   `hello` to stdout

   ```
   $ cat | cat
   hello 
   hello
   ```

Comment: `echo $(cat <<< "hello")`

Answer (score 3):

1. You should end your input with EOF (Ctrl+d) otherwise cat does not exit.
2. echo echoes the fd and then exits, thus closing the output descriptor of cat, which in response exits.
3. first cat's input is stdin, second's cat output is connected to stdout. first cat's output and second cat's input are connected together with a pipe.

Comment: about 2, in `command1 <(command2)`, are the two comands running at the same time, or one starts after the other finishes running?

Comment: these are running concurrently