# Implementation of process substitution, and concurrency in process substitution

Tags: linux, bash, process-substitution

Bash Manual says

> Process substitution is supported on systems that support named pipes ( fifos) or the `/dev/fd` method of naming open files.

1. Does it mean that process substition is implemented either in terms
   of named pipes, or in terms of a file under `/dev/fd`?
2. How is process substitution implemented in Linux?

   Does the following example mean that process substitution in Linux
   is implemented in terms of a file under `/dev/fd`, instead of named
   pipes?

   ```
   $ echo <(cat)
   /dev/fd/63
   ```
3. In `command1 <(command2)`, are the two comands running at the same
   time, or one starts after the other finishes running?

   If process substitution is implemented in terms of named pipes,
   does that mean that the two commands in the
   example of process substitution are running at the same time? My guess is because pipes and named pipes are used for communication between concurrently
   running processes, and the commands in a pipeline are running at the same time.

   I have this question when trying to understand the part 2 in a reply
   https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286556/674.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. From `strace` output of `strace -v -f -s150 -o log bash -c 'echo <(cat)'`, on my system, /dev/fd is implemented as pipe. It creates pipe with 3, 4 fds then dups 3 to 63.
2. `/dev/fd` is just a symlink to `/proc/self/fd`. My system lacks `/dev/fd` symlink and output is just `/proc/self/fd/63`. Bash just operates with pipes. In bash source code it's seems that it maybe emulated just like other bash'isms like `/dev/tcp` but I am not sure. I do not see these on `busybox ash` however.
3. If I replace `echo` builtin with `tty` and do `strace` over whole bash, I do see that `tty` runs first, then `cat` gets executed with preloaded pipe fds.

Answer (score 1):

1., 2.:  Yes, process substitution [is implemented in terms of named pipes](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/subst.c?h=devel&id=80df5e50417561d3da31f3de95b8678e6f102217#n5625) (open source = you can read the source)

3.

> If process substitution is implemented in terms of named pipes, does
>   that mean that the two commands in the example of process substitution
>   are running at the same time?

Yes, it does mean that they run concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

For point 3, If we define:

```
$ d(){ printf '%7s %7s %s\n' "$BASHPID" "$1" $(date -u +'%H:%M:%S'); }
$ p1(){ d START; readarray -t a; printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}" ; sleep 2; d END; }
$ p2(){ d START; sleep 2; d END; }
```

Then, this:

```
$ p1 < <(p2)
```

Will print:

```
   8517   START 20:31:38
  11764   START 20:31:38
  11764     END 20:31:40
   8517     END 20:31:42
```

That means that both start together, but p1 has to wait for p2 to end to close the read, then it sleep and ends.

In short: They run concurrently.